# Avoid css id and class variable name clashing across project

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

What is the best way *(besides making sure your class and id variable names are named differently every time)* to **not have a class or id name in one css file** in a **react/wepback project** clash/affect another css class or id in a different file?

For ex :

`file.js` has a div with id or className called `container`.
I have multiple css files throughout my project and some css files (more than 1) have `.container` variable in them.

How do I make sure upon webpacking / bundling / npm starting that these don't clash if I don't want to have to remember to name ever variable differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for avoid name clashing in css files. By using it you can localize the selector names.

> A CSS Module is a CSS file in which all class names and animation
>   names are scoped locally by default.

Also if you want global selectors, you can following syntax.

```
:global(.myclass){}
```